# What would Venus look like without acid clouds?

Tags: atmosphere, venus, planet

Despite its unpleasant surface conditions, Venus is undoubtedly one of the most beautiful worlds in the solar system when viewed from space. It’s huge clouds of sulphuric acid make the planet extremely reflective, so that it can even be seen from Earth as the Morning Star.

But what if these clouds disappeared? What would Venus look like then?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can think of two interpretations for this question right now:  what does Venus' surface look like underneath the clouds, or how would Venus (and its appearance) change if the atmosphere was so different that it didn't have the acid clouds in the first place

Comment: Already asked in Astro.SE: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12422/what-is-the-color-of-venus-if-it-has-no-atmosphere ... https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/53138/venus-atmosphere-color

Answer (score 5):

> What would Venus look like without acid clouds?

I guess this means visible light, and to my knowledge no color cameras have made it to the surface.

There is evidence of recent volcanic activity on Venus

- Nature News 15 March 2023, Correction 17 March 2023: [Volcanoes on Venus? ‘Striking’ finding hints at modern-day activity](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00783-x)

so I think the surface will have various minerals of different hues just like some volcanic areas on Earth (I'm thinking Yellowstone National Park) but certainly there isn't enough information to say exactly what it would look like during the day.

However, *at night* Venus may or may not look dull red.

Currently the surface glows with faintly visible red light due to thermal radiation. With a major change in cloud cover, the surface temperature may drop a bit, so we can't say for sure how much it would glow.

- [How brightly does Venus's hot surface glow at night? Could you see it? Could you see well enough to walk around?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58230/12102)
- Astronomy SE: [Has Hubble photographed Venus in near IR? If so how does it compare to the new and exciting Parker Solar Probe image?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41691/7982)

Comment: Recently asked in Astro.SE: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/53138/venus-atmosphere-color